# Merge two labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, merge

Good morning all,

I am looking to merge the labels as follows: MTB03 with CSF04 and MTB05 with CSF19. I should therefore end up with two labels: MTB03 / CSF04 and MTB05 / CSF19. There can be no data overlay because they are different.

I am also looking to transform my abscissa axis into percentages between 0 and 100%.

here is the piece of code to create this graphic :

MOZ_Echt <- subset_samples(MOZ, corebis == "CSF_04" | corebis == "MTB_03" | corebis == "MTB_05" | corebis == "CSF_19")

plot_bar(MOZ_Echt,fill="Domain",x="depth")+xlab("Depth (cm)")+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ facet_wrap(~corebis, scales = "free_x", ncol=2) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("878", "818", "718", "696", "646", "618", "596", "518", "418", "396", "346", "318", "296", "246", "218", "196", "131", "118", "18","13.5","8.5","5","3","1.5","0.5"))

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: additionally please also the code which you used to get those plots. Thanks